# Add Drools to a java project jar built with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, drools

I am fairly new to Gradle.

I am currently working on a project that uses Gradle to built the project. We now intend to use Drools as a rule engine. All the examples I have found online use Maven for Drools (7.7).

I have the following questions.

1. Is it necessary to run Drools 7.7 using Maven? If not, can anyone point in the direction of some examples using gradle.
2. Can Maven be used specifically in the project for Drools and Gradle for the rest of the project?

Comment: When talking about Drools and Maven, there are 2 different you may be talking about. You may be talking about building a project using the Drools libraries using Maven. Or you may be talking about how Drools may internally use Maven to resolve kjars (jar files containing rules). What are you talking about here?

Comment: Yes. I would like to know how Drools may use Maven internally. Would Maven need to be used at runtime or is there a way to by pass Maven entirely.

Comment: If you are creating your `KieBases` from resources inside your classpath, then Maven should not be used at all. 
I would say (even if I'm not 100% sure of it) that if you exclude `kie-ci` from your dependencies, maven is not going to be used at all.